# Java считывание данных (экономия памяти)

Tags: память, java, ввод

В консоли программе на Java подается большой массив числе типа long на одной строке.
Как я по результатам тестирования понял, программа сразу считывает все данные которые лежат на одной строке, а может даже больше.
А потом их по очереди выдает, т.е. программа держит все данные сразу в оперативной памяти.

Вопрос в том, правильно ли я понял вышеописанное, и есть ли способ считать только одно число, потом следующее и т.д. загружая в оперативную памяти их по очереди, а не одновременно?

Пробовал считывать через InputStream посимвольно и с помощью Scaner.

UPD Мы знаем количество чисел в строке.

Comment: На спичках решили сэкономить?

Comment: А цифры есть? Сколько байт читаете? Нельзя ж померять сферического коня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теоретически, можно надеть `Scanner` на `System.in` и читать по одному числу:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (in.hasNextInt())
{
    int num = in.nextInt();
    // обработка
}
```

Практически, не парьтесь, делайте как удобно. Не решайте проблему до того, как она возникла.

Comment: @VladD, Делал Scanner, но в оперативную память загружаются все данные сразу. И Scanner по очереди уже оттуда извлекает их.

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey: Но это уже не в ваших руках, это особенности реализации консольной подсистемы в той ОС, в которой вы работаете. Попробуйте написать вспомогательную программу, которая будет выводить данные в stdout по одному числу с паузами в секунду между двумя числами (только не забудьте flush после каждого числа), и перенаправьте её вывод на вход вашей программы. Посмотрите, как она будет принимать данные.

Comment: @VladD, для понятности поясню, что я имею дело с олимпиадной задачей, необходимо с одной строки считать порядка миллиона числе типа long, ограничения такие что мы не можем в оперативной памяти хранить столько данных, но по одному числу можем и сделать это надо за 2 секунду. Есть ли способ это сделать на java?

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey: А если у вас stdin будет такой большой, то и данные будут приходить наверняка кусками, а не целиком. Попробуйте!

Comment: @VladD, считав первое число программа сразу же потребляет более 20 мбайт.

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey: С точки зрения современных операционных систем, 20М — это что-то около нуля. Попробуйте реально большие входные данные, например, 1Г.

Comment: @VladD, с точки зрения промышленного кода - пустяк, на олимпиаде ограничение в 4 МБ, поэтому интересен факт, есть ли возможность считать данные на JAVA

Comment: видимо в данном случае java пролетает. Либо как то нужно учтывать и вычитать саму VM.

Comment: Сделайте на низком уровне. Читаете `read(byte[] b)` порциями по  2К.

Анализируете символы. Из кодов цифр вычисляете числа ( `s = s * 10 + c - '0'; ).

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey, @avp: вот ссылка из [википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#In_programming_contests): http://acm.tju.edu.cn/toj/faq.html#qj

> Since Java program runs slow, The time limit of each problem will be about twice of the original, and the _memory limit is enlarged to 1024M_.